# When opening csproj in VSCode, OmniSharp throws error

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, omnisharp

I'm using Fedora Linux, with the official VSCode package.

When opening a folder where my C# soulution is, OmniSharp throws:

```
Failed to load project file '/home/marko/Projects/My/Project/MyProject.csproj'.
/home/marko/Projects/My/Project/MyProject.csproj(1,1)
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The imported project "/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/15.0/Microsoft.Common.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  /usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/2.2.106/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/Sdk/Sdk.props
```

The csproj uses `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`.
The project builds and runs normally using `dotnet` in the terminal.
I have mono installed, but I've set `"omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "never"`

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is old, but for whoever still has this problem: removing Mono completely and then reinstalling all three dotnet core packages (**dotnet-host**, **dotnet-runtime** and **dotnet-sdk**) fixed this issue for me.